# Visual Studio crash when trying to run/deploy a Xamarin.Android application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using `MSVS2015Pro`.

I downloaded `Tasky` from: https://www.xamarin.com/getting-started/android.

Then, when I try to `run/deploy` it I get what you can see on the following image:

`Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working`

[image]

Then, if I got to `Windows / Computer Managment / System Tools / Event Viewer / Windows Logs / Applications` I get:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.StateManager.CreateBuildOnlyProjectStateSet(Project project)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.<SynchronizeWithBuildAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<CleanupAllLiveErrorsIfNeededAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<<OnSolutionBuild>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.StateManager.CreateBuildOnlyProjectStateSet(Project project)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.<SynchronizeWithBuildAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<CleanupAllLiveErrorsIfNeededAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<<OnSolutionBuild>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---

Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.TaskExtensions.ReportFatalErrorWorker(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetException(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ProcessInnerTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ProcessCompletedOuterTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InvokeCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

After that error popup window `MSVS2015Pro` closes and starts again (restart).

This is a loop.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: What is your VS Version information? Are you on the latest Visual Studio Update?

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but got a different issue in that the Tasky project is apparently targeting Android API 10 (got an error that API 10 SDK is not installed in the Android SDK Manager, which it is not on my machine). After changing the Compile and Target frameworks to Android SDK versions I have installed (e.g. 7.0 API 24) the app deployed and ran successfully. Can you try changing the Compile with and Target Framework properties in the project properties?